# Electric charge on a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

What is the electric charge on the capacitor with 3μF?
I've tried to apply Kirchhoff voltage law on each mesh, but isn't there
any short procedure for it?
Many thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Hint: Try removing all the other capacitors from the drawing. Now is it more obvious what the voltage is?

Comment: Hi. Did you find the answer using the conventional method. If yes, can you include it in your question. Version 1 of your question might be closed as off topic. Thanks.

Comment: A small hint for simplifying the network: The 1uF and 2uF capacitors are in parallel. This might simplify your calculations in using the conventional method.